# Pueden varios formularios de C# utilizar el mismo puerto serial para enviar y recibir datos?

Tags: c#, arduino

Estoy elaborando un proyecto con Arduino y C# y deseo que mi solucion de C# este compuesta por varios formularios y que utilicen el mismo puerto serial (ya que ese a sido mi inconveniente hasta el momento) y estaba pensando en que un camino facil seria una clase pero no se como se recepcionarian los datos de los formularios

Comment: Hola Jesús, bienvenido a SOes. Por favor, lee [tour] para que veas como funciona el sitio y [ask] para que veas como hacer una buena pregunta (hace falta que pongas lo que has intentado).

Comment: Tu clase debe funcionar como un "servicio"

Comment: Creo que eso es un patrón, Observer se llama.

Answer (score 0):

Para que todos tus formularios, a la hora de intentar mandar datos al Arduino, usen el mismo puerto, simplemente debes crearte una clase a parte que se encargue de ello. Por ejemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace *nombre_de_tu_proyecto*
{
public static class SerialPortClass
    {
    public static SerialPort serialPort1 { get; set; } = new SerialPort();
    }
}
```

Al ser una clase estática puedes llamarla desde cualquiera de tus formularios para escribir por ese puerto. Además, desde cualquier formulario puedes instanciar o modificar cualquiera de las propiedades del serialPort creado.